# How do I make a lookup formula also include a date range condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to return a text value based on other text values matching AND a row's date falling in between another specified date range.

I'll try to create a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Let's say I have the following table breaking out produce units sold by day:

ProduceTable:

[image: Screenshot]

---

Now, let's say that I have another table detailing the discounts that I ran for items during certain date ranges:

ProducePromoTable:

[image: Screenshot]

*[Edit: This example isn't great because the discount amounts are numerical, so ignore that and pretend that it's just text because that's what I'm really after. SUMIFS (I think) are off the table since I'm not trying to return a number value.]*

What I would like to do is pull the discount amount into the first table based on whether the type of produce matches AND checking for whether there was a discounted price on that item on that particular day.

I've tried some lookup combinations and index-match, but I haven't quite cracked the code.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried using a multi-criteria VLOOKUP, but that doesn't work because the date may not match exactly as it may fall within a range.

Any IF formulas I've tried allow me to nail down the initial criteria match, but not fetching the correct value based on said criteria.

I've also tried using a MATCH nested within an INDEX formula, but I can't figure out how to make that work in conjunction with the >= and <= date criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your other table is on a sheet named 'Discounts', then you can use this formula on cell D2 of the first table and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Discounts!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(1,INDEX((Discounts!$A$2:$A$6=B2)*(Discounts!$C$2:$C$6<=A2)*(Discounts!$D$2:$D$6>=A2),),0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **SUMPRODUCT function** to find your values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$5,SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$5=B2)*($H$2:$H$5<=A2)*($I$2:$I$5>=A2)*ROW($G$2:$G$5))-1),"Not in Range")
```

[image]